# Highlight, then fade highlight, for list items dynamically added to a list

Tags: jquery, css, highlighting

I have an unordered list on a page.  When that page is refreshed through Ajax, new list items may come back that will be dynamically added to the unordered list.  When the new list items get added, I would like to highlight those new list items, but fade the highlight out after a specified time.

I have tried animate and the jquery highlight effect, but have not found the right mixture to get a desired result.  What I am doing now, is to call a function after dynamically adding the list item to try to add a highlight class, and then remove that class, but that is not working as well.

The list items are generated and added to the unordered list through PHP.

How would I go about dynamically highlighting new list items after they have been dynamically added to an unordered list, but then fade that highlight out?

The desired result I am looking for is similar to how Scoopler's twitter feed behaves, [link text](http://www.scoopler.com/all/)

Comment: Post the code you have so far so we can help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var colorStr = '#DDDDFF'; // color of highlight
$("li.new").each(function (i,x) {
    $(this).css("background-color",colorStr);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(x).css("background-color","#ffffff"); // reset background
        $(x).effect("highlight", {color: colorStr}, 3000); // animate
    },3000);
});
```

Tested, I think this does what you want (that is, it holds the display for 3 seconds, and then gives a 3 second fadeout.

Comment: This gave me the idea to add a highlight class when my list items are added to the list using .animate( { backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 3000); to fade in the highlight, then I remove the highlight class after the animate has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

How about [jQuery livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code) plugin + highlight effect (assuming all li's in ul with id ulcontainer). Something along this lines should work.

```
var doIt = function() {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    // doIt empty so no highlight on first page load
    $('#ulcontainer > li').livequery(doIt);
    // now set doIt to something useful
    doIt = function() { $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000); };
});
// do ajax and add li's to ul#ulcontainer
```

Answer (score -1):

How about doing it as a two-step sequential animation.

1) Animate the highlight
2) Animate the fade-out

Do this in a sequence instead of in parallel.